# Substitute a variable in PDE of two variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, substitution

Let's say I have a function $f = f(x,y)$ and a differential equation where partial derivative appears, for example $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. I also have a substitution $t$, which contains both $x$ and $y$ variables, so, I guess, it's $t(x,y)$. How can I use this substitution to get derivative of an one-variable function, $\frac{df}{dx}$?

I understand, what I should do in a case with two substitutions: $t=t(x,y)$ and $p=p(x,y)$, I'd use a rule  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}$. But I'd still get a partial derivative and I don't have second substitution function.

Comment: So do you want to express partial derivatives of $g(x,t) = f(x,y)$, where the variable $y$ has been eliminated by substitution of $t(x,y)$?

Comment: What function is differentiated? $f(x(t),y(t))$? Generally speaking, the inverse function of $t(x,y)$ does not exist, so  $x,y$ is not a function of $t$. If  $(t,p)$ is a function of $(x,y)$, then the inverse function exists and the calculation goes thorough.